# Can I call a constructor from the constructor of another class in C#?

Tags: c#, constructor

I'm a newbie in C# and would like to know if, having two classes in the same namespace, I can call a constructor of one in a constructor of the other one?

For example:

```
class Company
{
    // COMPANY DETAILS
    Person owner;
    string name, website;

    Company()
    {
        this.owner = new Person();
    }
}
```

The above returns "Person.Person()" is inaccessible due to its protection level. Person class looks like this:

```
class Person
{
    // PERSONAL INFO
    private string name, surname;

    // DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR
    Person() 
    {
        this.name = "";
        this.surname = "";
    }
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing here? Shouldn't the constructor be accessible from wherever in the same namespace?

Comment: change "class Player" to "public class Player" ... or "public class Person".

Comment: Namespaces are irrelevant for access in C#. They just influence how verbosely you have to specify the identifier when referring to something in a given namespace.

Comment: @Flocke the most restrictive access modifier applies when one is not specified. For classes directly in a namespace, that access is `internal` (you cannot have `private` classes directly in a namespace) so the class itself is accessible assuming they are in the same assembly. The problem here is that the constructor also uses the most restrictive access modifier allowed for a method, in this case `private`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You defined the constructor as **private** hence you cannot access it.

The compiler even gives you a [hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0122):

```
error CS0122: 'Person.Person()' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

The [C# 6.0 specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/) state for [access modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#access-modifiers):

> When a *class_member_declaration* does not include any access modifiers, **private** is assumed.

whereas a [*class_member_declaration*](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#class-members) is specified as

```
class_member_declaration
    : ...
    | constructor_declaration
    | ...
    ;
```

Only [default constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#default-constructors) are public by default when the class is **not** defined as abstract.

Therefore change

```
Person() { }
```

to

```
public Person() { }
```

Comment: It works but seems odd that the constructors can't be called from within the same namespace...

Comment: @Stett  [Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/) have **nothing** to do with [access modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers).  They serve *very* different purposes.

Comment: Thank you Erik :)

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Some people may come from a Java background where packages and access modifiers are somewhat intermingled in purpose. Which might explain the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

In C# we have access modifiers. The current options are

```
Public - everyone has access
Internal - can only access from same assemnly
Protected - only the class and classes derived from the class can access members marked as protected
Protected Internal - accessible from any class in the same assembly or from any class derived from this class in any assembly
Private protected - only accessible from a class that is derived from this class AND in the same assembly 
Private - only accessible in the declaring class
```

There's a new one coming but let's leave that out.

What is important for your question is what things defualt to in code. A class with no access modifiers specified will default to internal. So anyone in the same assembly can see it. A class member, so a field, property, method, or **constructor** will default to private meaning only that class has access to it.

So for you you can leave your class declaration as it is if both your classes are in the same assembly (not Namespace those don't matter to access modifiers) so the default Internal access modifier is fine.

You need to change your Constructor to have an explicit internal or public modifier so you can access it. Just a note if you class is internal you can mark methods etc as public but they will still only be able to accessed from inside that assembly as the encapsulatong class is internal.

Comment: You're missing `protected internal` (`protected` **or** `internal`) which has always existed, and `private protected` (`protected` **and** `internal`) which is new in c#7

Comment: I had forgotten about protected internal yes! Thanks I'll stick that in. Is private protected released now?

Comment: Yes it is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private-protected